# SharePoint Reusable Workflow Risk Items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, project-online

I am trying to build a reusable workflow associated with the 'Risk' content type used by Project Web App Sub-sites. I am using Sharepoint Designer 2013.
Following the guidance [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33157.sharepoint-2013-create-reusable-workflow-on-content-type-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx)

Following this process in SD and selecting File, Add Item, Reusable Workflow, 'Specify the content type to associate with the new workflows' allows selection of many content types, (including a separate custom content type I've created) but not Risks. Risks however do appear in the content types available when selecting File, Add Item, List Workflow.

It is not an option to create a new custom content type, as the data extraction options we require are linked to the standard Risk content type.

Does anyone know why 'Risks' do not appear under the content types available for Reusable workflows?